# How to Fetch data from SQL Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have my CRUD in laravel and a SQL Database.
How can I fetch a database table data and print it in a Text Widget in Flutter ?

Comment: could you elaborate your questioin?do you want to fetch your laravel api inside the flutter and show in `Text` widget

Comment: @lava :Yes , I want to display some data from a column from a database table (ie: items remaining in stock) inside a text widget in a shop screen in my flutter app. I finished learning Flutter and laravel basics and I can't figure out a way to use them both together , I'm still newbie .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMggRcf2_do. try this  this tutorial if your total newbie.